# Got the ValueError when trying to print one of the fields in return string function __str__()

Tags: python, django

When I try to print(or to use in return string) one of the fields, I get the following ValueError:

**invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'topic_id'**

Here is my model class:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from languageTests.signals import topic_viewed_signal
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


User  = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
Topic = settings.TOPIC_MODEL

class TopicProgress(models.Model):
    user         = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete='CASCADE') # user instance instance.id
    topic        = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete='CASCADE')
    finished     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    started      = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('topic', 'user',)  

    def __str__(self):
        print("topic=<{}>".format(self.topic))
        return "{}-{}".format(self.user,self.topic)
```

Also this is the topic class:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    LEVELS = (
        ('b', 'Beginner'),
        ('i', 'Intermediate'),
        ('e', 'Expert'),
    )

    level = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LEVELS,
        blank=True,
        default='b',
        help_text='Tests level',
    )   

    title   = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a Test Name (e.g. Test #1)')
    objects = TopicManager()

    def return_level_str(self):
        dict_levels=dict(self.LEVELS)
        return dict_levels[self.level]    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('topic', args=[self.id])
```

I have tried to debug and figured out that "id" appears as string in 
**C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get**

```
args    
(<Q: (AND: ('id', 'topic_id'))>,)
kwargs  
{}
self    
<QuerySet [<Topic: sel>, <Topic: Past Perfect>]>
```

I have also tried to print other fields "finished" ,"started" , "user" and they all worked perfectly. Can someone shed light on this for me ?

here is the full traceback:

```
traceback:

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  163.             rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py" in get_cached_value
  13.             return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]

During handling of the above exception ('topic'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\base.py" in render
  33.         return super().render(context)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py" in render
  214.         _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in result_list
  341.             'results': list(results(cl))}

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in results
  318.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in __init__
  309.         super().__init__(*items)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  251.         if str(result_repr) == '':

File "C:\Users\A\Desktop\The-place\EnForFun\EnForFun\progress\models.py" in __str__
  21.         print("topic=<{}>".format(self.topic))

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  177.                 rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in get_object
  144.         return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  390.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1281.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1225.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_lookup
  1096.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  20.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  70.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  965.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/progress/progressprofile/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'topic_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted 'db' and everything worked.